# Global autocorrelation statistic for categorical data?

Tags: python, r, spatial, categorical-data, autocorrelation

Sorry for the dumb question, I have very limited experience with regards to spatial autocorrelation. I have a lot of spatial points for which I measured both continuous and categorical variables. I need to calculate **global** measures of spatial autocorrelation for both kinds of variables.
I know that this task is relatively easy for continuous ones, here an example using the package `elsa`:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(raster)
library(elsa)

dta <- data.frame(Lon = (runif(60)*100), 
                              Lat = (runif(60)*100), 
                              Cat = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 60, replace = T), 
                              Cont = (runif(60)*100))
coordinates(dta) <- ~Lon + Lat

# Moran's I global index:
moran(dta[,2], d1=0, d2=2000)
[1] -0.01694915 # The value varies given that seed was not set

# Geary's c global index:
geary(dta[,2], d1=0, d2=2000)
[1] 1
```

That is, I need something like the `moran` or `geary` commands in the previous example, but appliable to categorical covariates. I have been googleing for a while, but I have not been able to find a solution. I am more "fluent" in R than others, but Python o, perhapsm Julia, may also help. Any idea?